# alert if nothing happens on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click

essentially I am wondering if it is possible to write a function so that if any item inside a specific container is clicked and nothing happens, it will `alert` that the feature has not been made available yet.

## explanation:

what I mean by nothing happens is that the DOM or site does not change. So if a javascript or jquery function is called on click, it would not alert. if the item is a link to another site, it would not alert. but if nothing happens on the click event of an item inside a specified container, then it would alert.

Comment: can somebody please explain the -1, I feel like this is a very useful question

Comment: It might be because there is no code attempt shown.

Comment: Why do you need to detect if a button does something? Why can't you just manually put in an alert box in the code for each button that is not implemented?

Comment: I could do that, and I am right now. it just sparked the inspiration for this question because I thought it would be cool if this was easily possible

Answer (score 0):

The closest you could come would be to:

1. bind a click event handler to the container that would check if the [event target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) was a link to another site and, if not, display the alert
2. make sure you [stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) on all your event handlers.

Comment: it's more than just a link to another site...that would be easy...it is if there is any call to jquery or javascript as well

Comment: @RyanSaxe — That is handled in step 2 of the answer.

Comment: wouldn't that just prevent the other from happening, not detect if something does...

Comment: Yes, but since you won't want the alert to fire if your other event handler fires, that gives you the end result that you want.

Comment: could you give an example? I am still not sure how this will work

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EJ7gL/)

```
$('a').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).attr('href') == '#') {
        alert('the feature has not been made available yet.');
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: I am just answering his question.

Comment: in order to answer my question this needed to work with jquery event calls as well just like opening a dialog as @TusharGupta has pointed out